# plt.show() not rendering anything on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I've got the following code in Jupyter , curretly following a tutorial on DataCamp, however my plot is not getting generated.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.show()

seattle_weather_dic = {'MONTH':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
                   'MLY-TAVG-NORMAL':[42.1,43.4,46.6,50.5,56.0,61.0,65.9,66.5,61.6,53.3,46.2,41.1]} 
seattle_weather = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(seattle_weather_dic) 
ax.plot(seattle_weather["MONTH"], seattle_weather["MLY-TAVG-NORMAL"])
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think there should be `:` after `'MONTH'`

Comment: Also, ax is not defined. What do you see when you run this code?

Comment: Apologies, : after 'MONTH' is included in the original code. Made a mistake here. I'm not getting any errors when running the code

Comment: Try adding %matplotlib inline in the beginning of your notebook

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
seattle_weather_dic = {'MONTH':['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'],
                   'MLY-TAVG-NORMAL':[42.1,43.4,46.6,50.5,56.0,61.0,65.9,66.5,61.6,53.3,46.2,41.1]} 
seattle_weather = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(seattle_weather_dic) 
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(seattle_weather["MONTH"], seattle_weather["MLY-TAVG-NORMAL"])
plt.show()
```

I have defined `ax` and added a `:` after `'MONTH'`.